# WSO2 Stream processor: Siddhi App to calculate sum

Tags: wso2, wso2-streaming-integrator

I am working on stream processor 4.3.0. I have came across one scenario where I am putting some datafeeds into the rdbms table using siddhiapp. Using siddiapp, I am entering the data in RDBMS table as below

[image]

Now, I am using another SiddhiApp to retrieve the data, but I would want to try out to fetch the data in such way like below

[image]

As the common columns are shrinked to get into one row and the column which has counts are now summed to get the final Sum of all counts.

Can some one please guide me how to proceed here.

Thanks in advance

here is the app to get the total sum

```
    @App:name("IncomingStream3")
    @App:description("Description of the plan")

    -- Please refer to https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP400/Quick+Start+Guide on getting started with SP editor. 

    --@store(type = 'rdbms', datasource = 'APIM_ANALYTICS_DB')
    --@purge(enable='false', interval='60 min', @retentionPeriod(sec='1 day', min='72 hours', hours='90 days', days='1 year', months='2 years', years='3 years'))

    define stream  TempStatsStream (AGG_TIMESTAMP long, AGG_EVENT_TIMESTAMP long, apiName string, apiVersion string, apiResourcePath string,apiCreator string,username string, applicationConsumerKey string, AGG_LAST_EVENT_TIMESTAMP long, applicationName string, dateTime string, AGG_COUNT int);

    define aggregation StatsToCal

    from TempStatsStream
    select apiName, apiVersion, apiResourcePath, apiCreator, username, applicationName, 
    applicationConsumerKey, SUM (AGG_COUNT) as totalRequestCount, dateTime

    group by apiName, apiVersion, apiResourcePath, username, applicationConsumerKey
    aggregate by dateTime every days;
```

Only change I have made here is instead of fetching the value from DB table, I am considering it as stream ( as the aggregation can be done only for Stream, I suppose).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have to group by API, Name1, Name2 and ID? You can use `group by` similar to SQL group by

```
from TriggerStream join APITable
select APIName, Name1, Name2, ID, sum(Count) as totalCount
group by API, Name1, Name2, ID
insert into OutputStream;
```

Comment: To use SUM (COUNT), I am getting following error:
'SUM' is neither a function extension nor an aggregated attribute extension.

Comment: Is there any way you can share the siddhi app? As I cant reproduce this

Comment: I have added the app.

Comment: Hi, it seems uppercase sum doesn't work, try all low caps. Siddhi `aggregations` are not tables, these are native siddhi function which allows you to define summarisation per granularity easily. BTW, are you trying to get data from aggregation that is already defined or trying to create new aggregation? https://siddhi.io/en/v5.0/docs/query-guide/#named-aggregation

Comment: I am creating a new aggregation after taking it from DB

Comment: In the DB is it raw events? or already summarised data? I am asking because you had AGG_EVENT_TIMESTAMP in the stream. This is an internal config of an aggregation. I think you are looking at an aggregation table. When you define an aggregation this is mapped to various _SECONDS, _MINUTES and _HOURS table. That means you already have summarised data you just need to query siddhi

Comment: Also seems like you are using APIM analytics? All the tables expect that related to alerts are aggregation tables :)

Comment: ok. Thanks for the info. But I have few more questions on how does it works. When I am performing aggregating for days, at what time does the new entries come in Database. Is it everyday at 12:00am GMT?

Comment: Also, when we use aggregation function for Days in siddhi apps, does it perform aggregation from Hours table which is already present in Database or it aggregates at run time as per scheduled time directly from APIM events?

Comment: Siddhi aggregation uses steaming lambda architecture, for each duration defined in the aggregation an in-memory store is kept along with a table when a granularity expires, events are pushed to the duration next in line as well as to the table. https://siddhi.io/en/v5.0/development/architecture/#siddhi-aggregation